# NoClassDefFoundError at run time while compilation is ok

Tags: java, jsoup

There is a jar file in my java project and I want to deploy it while my code is running. The commands I use are

```
javac -cp /home/mahmood/excel-cmd/jsoup-1.10.3.jar -verbose *.java
java TheFrame
```

Everything is fine and I don't see any error. However, when the program reaches a method from jsoup

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
...
Document doc = doc = Jsoup.connect("A URL")
        .data("f1", gName)
        .data("ajax", "1")
        .post();
```

it fails with this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup
```

The full output is available at [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/JRBChczi). If I drop the `-cp` then I get some compile errors relating to the jsoup methods that are undefined. So, I wonder why it fail at the run time. How can I fix that?

Comment: The jsoup jar of course needs to be in the runtime classpath, too. How could your TheFrame class use classes from JSoup if JSoup classes are not available from the classpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

java -cp .:/path/to/jar/file Myprogram

So in your case it would be

```
java -cp .:/home/mahmood/excel-cmd/jsoup-1.10.3.jar TheFrame
```